# Is there an HTML linter that will make sure attributes are aligned properly on an element?

Tags: html, format, lint, merge-request, htmllint

Is there any type of command line HTML linter that I can use to enforce that attributes are aligned properly? We have a code standard that says you can **NOT** do this:

```
  <select id="work-log-type" [(ngModel)]="WorkLog.Type" name="type"
                        required>                    
                </select>
```

**It has to be like this**

```
 <select id="work-log-type"
         [(ngModel)]="WorkLog.Type"
         name="type"
         required>
 </select>
```

This is an Angular 9 Project using Visual Studio Code. I can have people also install code formatters, but I am looking for something they can run at their command line to enforce it and perhaps in the pipeline. My goal is to get these issues fixed before someone has to do their code review. I also want to say this is not my rule, but I have to abide by it